# using segbot xacro file to generate urdf

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Recently I am trying to use the segbot xacro file in the urdf and robots folders (https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot), However, it turned out that the generated file of URDF is blank.

Could anyone provide some suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Cheers,
Lili

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91981/using-segbot-xacro-file-to-generate-urdf/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Lili Meng: See this thread for the answer http://answers.ros.org/question/62646/please-help-converting-urdfxacro-to-sdf/?answer=92051#post-id-92051

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1